# How to seed data with PostgreSQL in .NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

My goal is to populate the database with data from a .json file. In the code below, I try to do this through a separate static method and a program.cs class. I am using a PostgreSQL database. After I used the "dotnet run" command the database remains without the data I want to seed. What am I doing wrong? Where could the problem be?

```
public static async Task SeedAsync(DataContext context, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if(!context.Books.Any())
        {
            var booksData = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\szzie\\books.json");
            var books = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Book>>(booksData);

            foreach (var book in books)
            {
                context.Books.Add(book);
            }

                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        using(var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            var loggerFactory = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
            try
            {
                var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
                await context.Database.MigrateAsync();
                await SeedData.SeedAsync(context, loggerFactory);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
                logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        host.Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `books` has any books in it after deserialization? Can you please add sample json file you are using and the `Book` class?

Comment: Also note there is no need for `foreach`, just `context.Books.AddRange(books)`;

Comment: As an aside, .NET 5 is no longer supported. You should upgrade to .NET 6/7.

Comment: Are you using EF Core?